# How can I execute batches of requests simultaneously in python?

Tags: python, multithreading, asynchronous, praw, grequests

I'm using the Reddit api to upvote some subreddits. I'd like to upvote multiple subreddits simultaneously, using the `praw` library to interact with the reddit api.

I want to upvote the 27 "hot" and "rising" posts of /r/bookclub:

```
subreddit = reddit.subreddit("bookclub")

for submission in subreddit.hot(limit=27):
    submission.upvote()

for submission in subreddit.rising(limit=27):
    submission.upvote()
```

I'd like to use async or multiprocessing to do this faster. I used the `grequests` library to do all the `.upvote()` at once, and it's working so far, but I'm not sure if it's really better:

```
subreddit = reddit.subreddit("bookclub")

hot_upvotes = (grequests.get(submission.upvote()) for submission in subreddit.hot(limit=27))
grequests.map(hot_upvotes)

rising_upvotes = (grequests.get(submission.upvote()) for submission in subreddit.rising(limit=27))
grequests.map(rising_upvotes)
```

Both versions upvote the subreddit. What I am wondering is if it is possible to run the `hot_upvotes` and `rising_upvotes` portions at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from threading import Thread
import functools

subreddit = reddit.subreddit("bookclub")

def run_hot_upvotes(subreddit):
    hot_upvotes = (grequests.get(submission.upvote()) for submission in subreddit.hot(limit=27))
    grequests.map(hot_upvotes)

def run_rising_upvotes(subreddit):
    rising_upvotes = (grequests.get(submission.upvote()) for submission in subreddit.rising(limit=27))
    grequests.map(rising_upvotes)

Thread(target = functools.partial(run_rising_upvotes, subreddit)).start()
Thread(target = functools.partial(run_hot_upvotes, subreddit)).start()
```

Try the following to have both run at the same time, each in its own thread.

Comment: Is there a way to pass an argument to the `run_hot_upvotes()` and `run_rising_upvotes()` functions when they are run? Like `run_hot_upvotes(subreddit)`

Comment: I get a `NameError: global name 'subreddit' is not defined`. Need to figure out how to pass it to each function.

Comment: I added an `args` and it worked. `Thread(target=run_hot_upvotes, args=(subreddit,)).start()`

Comment: Great, I also updated my answer to use a `functools.partial` instead of `args` which basically ends up in being the same thing.